# Jquery datetimepicker - first day of week

Tags: jquery

Hello I have a problem with jquery datetimepicker. I would like to display the calendar at the beginning of the week on Monday (now it's Sunday). I used `firstDay`, but it does nothing.
Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   'use strict';
   jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('cs');
   jQuery('#startDate, #endDate').datetimepicker({
       format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
       firstDay: 1,
       step: 15
    });
 });

<input class="form-control" id="startDate" datetime-picker   />
```

How to displayed calendar with start of week in Monday? Thank you

Comment: https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#dayOfWeekStart

Comment: do you want to only show Mondays or do you want the user to only be able to select Mondays from the calendar?

Comment: No i want to show whole week but monday in first place (now i was sunday). `dayOfWeekStart` is good solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation (xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#dayOfWeekStart), to adjust the week starting day from Sunday to Monday you'd provide the option of `dayOfWeekStart: 1`

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation here: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#show-week
`firstDay: 1` will display Monday as the first day of the week. This also works in my application.

UPDATE: I didn't notice the question was about DateTimePicker, and not DatePicker. Nor did I know there was a DateTimePicker, and also a DateTimePicker is not to be found on the website I referred to. Wherever the DateTimePicker can be found, I think it's a bit odd if the parameters really aren't consistent.

Answer (score 0):

```
moment.locale('en', {
    week : {
        dow : 1, // Monday is the first day of the week.
    }
});
```

This worked for me. It changes the setting for locale `en` for first day of the week to Monday. For some reason unknown to me `en` was originally set to Sunday in my moment locales.